# haproxy to icecast front end connection close

Tags: haproxy, icecast

I'm looking for a solution for load balancing icecast,
basically im using haproxy as the load balancer,
although unlikely should haproxy go down I need the client connection be still established to the backend icecast server

does anyone know the configuration for this? I have tried almost everything but if i stop haproxy the client loses connection to the icecast stream.

Many thanks in advance

MooseH

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to put Icecast behind a "haproxy". It's incredibly stable and the added complexity makes it much more likely that problems will occur. There are e.g. known problems with reverse proxying Icecast.

For improved availability, I'd recommend having a look in the direction of multiple Icecast servers and e.g. round-robin DNS or an HTTP redirector. Icecast has master-slave capability to replicate all streams to a cluster.

Comment: There is when you're taking 318 million requests a month :D, this is hosting one of the biggest audio streaming network in the UK and we are looking for solutions to improve our load balancing, we have tried DNS but but this doesn't truly load balance and doesnt do sticky sessions. its a little hard to explain but we need people to go back to the server they were on before, we were using 302 redirect scripts but they are problematic for the clients, its certainly a hard one, we are already implementing fallback mounts. but this  doesnt fix our "one route" solution

Comment: Hmm, added context could help. What are you really trying to solve by using HAproxy? In which mode are you using HAproxy? [I do know of larger Icecast deployments than yours that just run plain Icecast though]

Comment: We have 1 ingest, then 9 relay servers to an ingest, we have manipulated icecast to added a session cookie, and the user gets metadata using that session cookie, but if they hit another server it will not know their session so we have to have sticky /round robin load balancing, we have to use http load balancing due to the sticky part. the bit we are saving is not having our customers 302 redirect and evenly distributing the load across our edges, we have 9000 concurrent connections icecast is stable around 3000 each (but we leave a lot of legroom) 50% free is our company rule.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still of relevance, but would a shared session store maybe help. you could use redis to store the metadata and have the servers query it when a request with a cookie comes in. I never did that, just an idea

Comment: From my experience, Icecast's built-in TLS listener doesn't scale well, so there is certainly a good reason to consider a load balancer to terminate TLS. When you reach several hundred concurrent listeners, Icecast seems to take over a second to finish the handshake and start sending data.

Answer (score 0):

Setup an assignment service that randomly assigns listeners to a pool of icecast servers using 301 redirects.

Point all listeners something like http://feed.mydomain.com - have this server "know" which icecast servers are online and ready to receive requests.  Then simply randomly, round robin, or smartly based on numbers of listeners send a 301 redirect to a pool of servers.